# python use inputs build stacks

Tags: python, input, stack, simulation

I'm trying to use inputs(such as use raw_input()) to create stacks.
Input:
The first line of the input contains the total number of stack operations N,
0 < N ≤ 100000. Each of the next N lines contains a description of a stack
operation, either in the form PUSH A B (meaning to push B into stack A),
or in the form POP A (meaning to pop an element from stack A), where A is
the number of stack (1 ≤ A ≤ 1000), and B is an integer (0 ≤ B ≤ 109). You
may assume, that every operation is correct (i.e., before each POP operation,
the respective stack is not empty).

Output:
For each POP operation, described in the input, output the value, which this
POP operation gets from the top of that stack, to which it is applied. Numbers
should appear according to the order of the POP operations in the input.
Each number should be output in a separate line.

Here are some sample inputs and out puts:

Sample Input:

7

PUSH 1 100

PUSH 1 200

PUSH 2 300

PUSH 2 400

POP 2

POP 1

POP 2

Sample Output:

400

200

300

Thanks

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This sounds like a heaped queue.  If so, Python already has an implementation if you're not trying to do this for a class or learning exercise.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Comment: I'm trying to define my own file, can include class or only methods. Can't use build-in stack/queue from  docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html.

Comment: List of initially empty lists for the stacks. Index to choose the stack. Built in list append and pop for operations

Comment: What are you asking for? This question looks suspiciously like those found on online judging sites, in which case what is the point of asking for the solution here? If you have had a go at solving it yourself, post what you have tried and describe where you are having difficulties.

Comment: This is your third of three "do my homework for me" question you posted. Please refrain.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code to get you started. This uses list to support stack's push & pop operations.
Note: this is not a robust code. Only to demo how to use list for your use case.

```
stacks = {}


def push(s_id, data):
    if s_id not in stacks:
        stacks[s_id] = []
    stacks[s_id].append(data)


def pop(s_id):
    return stacks[s_id].pop()


f = open("input")
N = int(f.readline())
for i in range(N):
    tokens = f.readline().split()
    op = tokens[0]
    if op == "PUSH":
        push(tokens[1], tokens[2])
    if op == "POP":
        print pop(tokens[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try write your own stack class, but you don't have to write

Class Stack:
    def pop():
        # bla
    def push(value):
        #bla
    def **init**():
        #bla…

No.

Standard list has methods pop and append (append works like push).

You can write:

Stack1=[]

Stack2=[]

And parse input file and call appropriate methods.